# Tomcat database connection pool slow in high throughput

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jdbctemplate, tomcat-jdbc

I have soap webservice written in Spring 2.X and which connect to  *Teradata* and return the result to client. To connect the data based I am using [*Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool*](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) as the `DataSource`.

In peak hour (9AM to 6PM) application get about 60k transactions requests. I observed some of the transactions goes in hung state and return response in 2-3 minutes . I suspect some transaction goes in wait status and once connection is available in pool then complete the transactions.

Below is the configuration for the `DataSource`.

```
    <bean id="dataSource"   class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"/>
        <property name="url" >
            <util:constant static-field=" _DB_HOST"/>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <util:constant static-field=" DB_USER"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <util:constant static-field=" DB_PWD"/>
        </property>
        <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="0" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="-1" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1000" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1000" />

    </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <qualifier value="txnMngr"/>
    </bean>

// using JdbcTemplate to read the data from data base.
```

Here are my questions:

- Is there any issue with above configuration based on the load which I mentioned for my application?
- Is there any way I can monitor the DB connection pool uses?

Comment: @BasilBourque Tomcat version is 9.0.44

Comment: Post such details as edits to your Question rather than as Commment.

Comment: “60k transactions requests” – how often? Every minute, per hour?

Comment: @BasilBourque , every hour i get 6-7 thousand of request and in about 8-9 hours i get about 60+ transactions.  Is that above Connection Pool configuration is correct for these number of request? and is there anyway to monitor the connection pool in Tomcat?